# how to use richtextfx with javafx textarea

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder, richtextfx

I don't understand how to use Mikula's richtextfx with the built-in javafx text area control. Can someone take me through this step-by-step?

My goal is simply to use richtextfx to get a current line/row in this text area and/or count the lines/rows with text wrapping enabled.

Comment: RichTextFX is a replacement for the JavaFX TextArea so your question is bogus

Comment: Well, how would I use RichTextFX with Scene Builder 2.0 (ie. if I wanted to replace my text area with the corresponding Rich Text FX control)? Is it even possible to add the RichTextFX controls into Scene Builder??

Comment: Looks like this is not working - see https://www.bountysource.com/issues/26506782-controls-not-recognized-in-scene-builder-2-0 but you should have found that yourself with google :-(